# Getting error after executing my python script with COM object

Tags: python-3.x

I have written class for developing COM sever in 64 bit windows 7 operating system using python 33 64bit

```
import pythoncom

class PythonUtilities:
    _public_methods_ = [ 'SplitString' ]
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonDemos.Utilities"
    _reg_clsid_ = "{41E24E95-D45A-11D2-852C-204C4F4F5020}"

    def SplitString(self, val, item=None):
        import string
        if item != None: item = str(item)
        return string.split(str(val), item)

if __name__=='__main__':
    print "Registering COM server..."
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
```

but when i am executing i am getting this error

> Registering COM Server...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "SimpleCOMServer.py", line 3, in 
>       class PythonUtilities:
>     File "SimpleCOMServer.py", line 13, in PythonUtilities
>       win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonUtilities)
>   NameError: name 'PythonUtilities' is not defined

Please help me where i have done the mistake.

Comment: `print` is a function in python3. Also, are you sure about the capitalisation of `Class`  & `If`?